# How to test function inside ngOnInit

Tags: angular, angular-test

My component class is simple. It takes an input from parent component and based on that input it resolves a parameter from an ENUM inside the `ngOnInit`

My Component class:

```js
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {
@Input() serviceType: string;
serviceUrl : string;

ngOnInit() {
        this.findServiceType();
    }
    
findServiceType= () => {
        if (this.serviceType) {
            if (this.serviceType === 't1') {
                this.serviceUrl = TestFileEnumConstants.T1_URL;
            }else if (this.serviceType === 't2') {
                this.serviceUrl = TestFileEnumConstants.T2_URL;
            }
        }
    }
    
 }
```

My Test Class:

```js
describe('testcomponent', () => {

    let component: TestComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<TestComponent>;
    let mockService = <Serv1>{};
    
    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [FormsModule],
            declarations: [
                TestComponent, TestChildComponent],
            providers: [
                { provide: MockService, useValue: mockService }
                ]
        });
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
    });
    
    it('should create testcomponent', () => {
        expect(component).toBeDefined();
    });
    
     describe('testType1',  () => {
        beforeEach( () => {
            spyOn(component, 'findServiceType');
            
        });
        it('should correctly wire url based on type1', () => {
            component.serviceType = 'type1';
            fixture.detectChanges(); 
            expect(component.findServiceType).toHaveBeenCalled();
            expect(component.serviceUrl).toBe(TestFileEnumConstants.T1_URL)
        });
    });
    
    }
```

The issue is `serviceUrl` is not getting poluplated because 'serviceType' - the input is coming as `undefined` even after change detection is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was because of a `SpyOn` statement in the `beforEach()` segment. Since the mock function is not returning any data, the return value keep on getting `undefined`. The problem statement is given below, I have to comment the `spyOn` statement:

```js
beforeEach( () => {
            // spyOn(component, 'findServiceType');
            
        });
```

Removed this function and worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

You should create two tests instead of the one. The first one testing if the `this.findServiceType();` is called on `ngOnInit` and then a second test that tests the functionality of `findServiceType` in isolation.

```
it('should correctly wire url based on type1', () => {
   component.serviceType = 'type1';
   component.findServiceType()

   expect(component.serviceUrl)
       .toBe(TestFileEnumConstants.T1_URL)
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the info, I updated my test cases like you said. The real issue I was facing was because of a mocking statement - `spyOn(component, 'findServiceType');`. I have updated the answer.